# How to stop Windows (11 Pro) from re-confirming app defaults after new software is installed?

Tags: windows-11, file-association

I'm on Windows 11 Pro (22H2) -- is there any way to stop Windows from prompting to re-confirm default apps / file associations whenever new software is installed? I've tried Googling for a setting, but all I get is tutorials for how to set the defaults.

Or, put another way: if an app default has already been set, is there any way to discourage Windows from asking me if I want to change it?

Here's an example scenario: I'd diligently gone through and set default apps for a load of image file format extensions, so when I double click them in Windows Explorer, they open in my desired application. Then I installed Gimp, the art package. Subsequently when I double click a .JPG, .JPEG, .JPE, .PNG, .WEBP, etc. etc. instead of launching the default, Windows pops up the familiar selection menu again and asks me to re-confirm which app I'd like to use.

To be clear: my current defaults have not been changed by Gimp (I've checked in Settings.) Also, once I've re-confirmed that I want to continue to use the current default, the prompt doesn't appear again. I assume(?) this is Windows trying to be useful by giving me the option to switch defaults to the newly installed software or stick with the current default -- but it's a pain, particularly for A/V data where there's a mass of competing file formats and a lot of software that can handle multiple formats. Every time I install any software that handles images or video or audio I'm always dreading whether I'll have to re-confirm defaults for dozens of file extensions. So the ability to switch this off would be useful.

Comment: This is a long-standing issue. You can set a Registry key, `NoOpenWith`, to prevent one app from high-jacking an extension (https://winaero.com/prevent-windows-10-from-resetting-your-default-apps/), but https://superuser.com/questions/1353653/prevent-windows-10-from-resetting-default-applications showed no answer for preventing re-confirmation. There is a tool that *might* help, https://www.thewindowsclub.com/stop-windows-10-resetting-default-apps, but I've not tested it.